# Closure of span of $e^{in\theta}$ for $n \geq 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, banach-spaces

> For $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, consider the functions $\varphi_n \in L^1(\mathbb{T})$ defined by $\varphi_n(e^{i\theta}) = e^{in\theta}$. Consider the subspace $M_0 = \operatorname{span}\{\varphi_n: n \geq 0\} \subset L^1(\mathbb{T})$ and let $M$ be the closure of $M_0$ in $L^1(\mathbb{T})$. Does $\varphi_n \in M$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $n < 0$?

Intuitively, it seems that $e^{-i\theta}$ may not be in $M$, but I am unable to formalize this. I have also seen the following hint from a previous question.

> If $M$ is a closed subspace of a Banach space, then $v \in M$ if $\psi \in X^*$ and $\psi(M) = 0$ implies $\psi(v) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\varphi_n^*=\overline{\varphi_n}$ treated as a member of $L_\infty(\mathbb{T})$ and note that $\|\varphi_n^*\|_\infty=1$.  Note that $$\langle \varphi_m^*, \varphi_n\rangle=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-im\theta}e^{in\theta}d\theta=0$$ if $m\neq n$, and this equals $1$ if $m=n$. Here I'm assuming normalized Haar measure on $\mathbb{T}$.

Assume that for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $B\subset \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n\notin B$ and $|B|<\infty$, let $g=\sum_{k\in B}a_k\varphi_k$.  Then $$\|\varphi_n-g\|_1 \geqslant \langle \varphi_n^*,\varphi_n-g\rangle = 1.$$  This is because $$\langle \varphi^*_n,g\rangle = \sum_{k\in B}a_k \langle \varphi_n^*,\varphi_k\rangle=0,$$ since $k\neq n$ for each $k\in B$.

From this it follows that if $B\subset \mathbb{Z}$ is any (finite or not) subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ which does not contain $n$, then $\text{dist}(\varphi_n, \text{span}\{\varphi_k:k\in B\})\geqslant 1$.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks (+1)!

Answer (score 0):

For every fixed $n>0$ and $f\in M_0$ we have
$$\int\limits_{\mathbb{T}}f(x)e^{inx}\,dx =0 \quad (*)$$ By continuity $(*)$ extends to all $f\in M.$ But the identity $(*)$ does not hold for $f=e^{-inx},$ therefore $e^{-inx}\notin M.$ Moreover
$$\|e^{-inx}-f\|_1\ge \int\limits_{\mathbb{T}}[e^{-inx}-f]e^{inx}\,dx =1,\quad f\in M$$ Hence ${\rm dist}(e^{-inx},M)\ge 1.$ Actually  ${\rm dist}(e^{-inx},M)= 1,$ as $\|e^{-inx}\|_\infty =1.$